# HttpClient failing

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, httpclient, portable-class-library

When I run my app on the emulator for iOS it works fine. When I run it on a device the first call to HttpClient fails. My class containing the HttpClient calls is in a PCL. It looks like an instance of [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20589).

However, the documented workarounds of adding the following to your iOS project app.config does not work for me (the system.net.http addition);

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    ......
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

With this in my app.config, the following method successfully retrieves the data from the server, but fails to read it.  The bottom line containing ReadAsAsync(..) fails and throws an exception.  The exception is 'null' and nothing is output to the terminal either. It works fine on the emulator, but not the device.

```
    public async Task<List<ExternalLoginViewModel>> GetExternalLoginsAsync()
    {
        using (var client = GetNewHttpClient(false))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");

            var response = await client.GetAsync("api/account/externalLogins?returnUrl=/&generateState=true");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

             return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ExternalLoginViewModel>>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"...the first call to HttpClient fails"* - How does it fail?

Comment: It fails in a special way :-)  I think because its Xamarin.. there's no output and the exception is "null".

Comment: Config files are not supported on the mobile profile, that would explain why that workaround fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by uninstalling the "Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries" nuget package from both the PCL and the iOS project. Then reinstalling on both. The iOS project has references now to 'System.Net.Http.Extensions' and to 'System.Net.Http.Primatives' but does not contain one to 'System.Net.Http'. The following binding redirect is used in the app.config file in the iOS project as well;

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly binding redirection is wrong. Your iOS project should have an app.config file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.5.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The reason for the redirect is that the `Microsoft.Net.HttpClient` packages contains the `System.Net.HttpClient` namespace but that already exists on iOS and Android (with slightly different features even). At runtime it will resolve to the wrong assembly and not use the (Xamarin-)native iOS one.

You can find a demo project for iOS, Android and WP8 based on HttpClient in a PCL at my [Github repo](https://github.com/Krumelur/HttpClientTest).

Comment: When i use this, I get an exception thrown on my call to postasjsonasync(). The exception says "A type load exception occured". And the message is: ""Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[T]' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, …"".   If I remove this from the app.config it works fine again.

Comment: Did you use the demo from the repo?

Comment: I followed the instructions on the repo under iOS project.  I added the section to app.config and the one line to packages.config.  I have edited my main post to show you the entire error that is thrown when any call to 'postasjsonasync()' happens.

Comment: This error is happening in the emulator.  With your config file changes, this should work in both the emulator AND the device, correct?  I don't need to change this every time I deploy to a different target? (device vs emulator) ?

Comment: That is correct. Does the demo from the repo work for you (without changes)?

Comment: The demo project gives me the error shown here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16571/error-mt1001-could-not-find-an-application-at-the-specified-directory

Comment: I have made my project identical to the demo. With these changes, the device gets past the initial call to "GetAsync()" but fails the call to "response.Content.ReadAsAsync()" with an empty (null) error. I haave updated my initial question.