# Portable Class Library in Xamarin working on iOS Simulator but not on device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

We have a Xamarin cross-platform app that is using a custom Portable Class Library to interface with our company's API. The issue we are experiencing is that when we make a request through the PCL using the app on the iOS Simulator, everything works as expected, but when we try to do the same thing on an actual device, we get a "Bad Request" error code back from our API.

We have been able to determine that when the app is running on the device, the body parameters in the post we are making are null, but when we do the same thing on the simulator, the parameters have the values we have passed in.

Our PCL is using System.Net.HttpClient, so we thought that this answer might help: [HttpClient failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521738/httpclient-failing)
Sadly, this didn't work because it appears that Xamarin apps don't use an app.config file anyway.

We have tried checking to make sure that both our PCL and our iOS project are referencing the same version of System.Net.HttpClient, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue either.

We also tried the workarounds in the following bug report to no avail: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20589

This article had helped us in the past, but it doesn't seem to be helping this situation:
[HttpClient missing from .Net portable subset while creating PCL in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844262/httpclient-missing-from-net-portable-subset-while-creating-pcl-in-xamarin?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **several** differences when an application runs on the simulator and on a device.

One of them is that the managed linker is disable on simulator builds (it's faster when the JIT is used) while it's enabled for device builds (same logic: it's faster for AOT builds).

It's possible that your application uses reflection (directly or indirectly) and needs to preserve some members (e.g. serialization).

You can try this by either enabling the managed linker on the simulator build (or disabling it on device builds). That will tell you if your issue is related to the managed linker (or not).

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the linker was enabled for the device build but disabled for the simulator. Disabling the linker for the device build solved the problem.  Do you know if this will potentially affect the performance/stability of the app when it comes time for release?

Comment: Yes, without the linker your application will be **HUGE** as it will include most of the BCL and none of the optimizations the linker can do. You need to find and preserve the members used thru reflection.